# If $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is a basis of V, so is $\{v_1+v_2,v_1-v_2\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi I need help with the completion of this proof, I believe I am nearly at the end but I do not know how to end it

Proof: If v1 and v2 are a basis of v, then a**v1**+b**v2**=**v** for all v element of v.
Then if **v1**+**v2**, **v1**-**v2** is a basis, c(**v1**+**v2**)+d(**v1**-**v2**) = **v**

Then by simplification I get **v1**(c+d)+**v2**(c-d) = v

Then this implies c+d=a and c-d=b
I do not know where to go from here, does this mean I can just assume this is a valid basis? May seem like a really silly question so sorry!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Please** use Mathjax : for example, v with an index i is obtained by writing : dollar sign, letter v, underscore symbol, letter i dollar sign

Answer (score 2):

Here is another - more direct - proof:

Basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is sent onto system  $\{v_1+v_2,v_1-v_2\}$ by a linear application $L$ with matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&\ \ 1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

which is invertible. Thus $L$ is bijective ; therefore $\{v_1+v_2,v_1-v_2\}$ is a basis also.

Answer (score 0):

You've shown that the new vectors have the same span as the originals (almost--you should find explicit expressions for $c$ and $d$). Now, you need to show that $\vec{v}_1 + \vec{v}_2$ and $\vec{v}_1-\vec{v}_2$ are linearly independent.